# SaltStack: How to avoid write-protected files/directories after achive.extracted?

Tags: salt-stack

After archive.extracted (SaltStack 2018.3.2) of a large zip file on a Win2012r2 minion all extracted files and directories are write protected. Is there an option I am missing or any other way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you check what are permissions after extracting it?

Comment: The crucial users have full control - however, the read-only flag is set.